# Failed Signup with Devise nested parameters model have serialized column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, devise, jsonb

During a signup process I have a user model and Tenant model. Recently I added a serialized column to the Tenant model and I can update the this column fine. However when creating a new Tenant I have devise creating tenant through nested parameters and I get the following error:
`ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch (Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String. -- "{}")`: Important to note that I don't touch that column during the sign up process I have tried including the column on the sanitizer but it does the same. On the schema there is a default value which is '{}'. Below some of the code:

```
create_table "tenants", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "tenant_name"
   t.string   "tenant_address"
   t.string   "tenant_city"
   t.string   "tenant_zip"
   t.string   "tenant_phone"
   t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
   t.boolean  "authorized"
   t.boolean  "trial"
   t.string   "plan_id"
   t.string   "plan_name"
   t.string   "braintree_id"
   t.string   "subscription_id"
   t.jsonb    "preferences",     default: "{}", null: false
   t.string   "tenant_state"
   t.string   "tenant_country"
   t.index ["preferences"], name: "index_tenants_on_preferences", using: :gin
```

end

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, :dependent =>  :delete_all
  has_many :customers, :dependent =>  :delete_all
  has_many :work_orders, :dependent =>  :delete_all
  has_many :vehicles, :dependent =>  :delete_all
  has_many :suppliers, :dependent => :delete_all
end

 serialize :preferences, Hash
 store_accessor :preferences, :state_tax, :mun_tax, :welcome_sms,       :estimate_sms, :completed_sms, :disclaimer
```

Here is part of my User controller:

```
   class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
     # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

   # GET /resource/sign_up
    def new
      build_resource({})
      self.resource.tenant = Tenant.new
       respond_with self.resource
     end

   # POST /resource
    def create
    super
    if @user.save
     @result = Braintree::Customer.create(
        :first_name =>  @user.name,
        :last_name => @user.lastname,
        :company => @user.tenant.tenant_name,
        :email => @user.email,
        :phone => @user.phone
        )
         if @result.success?
         @user.tenant.set_braintree_id(@result.customer.id)
         flash[:notice] = 'Thanks you!  and Welcome to Autokick.tech enjoy    your free 30 days!'
        else
          flash[:notice] = @result.errors
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`t.jsonb    "preferences",     default: "{}", null: false`

The default is a string `"{}"` like the error says.
Change it to `default: {}` without the quotes.